# $(.class).eq().append appends to wrong class after working twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an App that reads a log file, generates cards images from it and then stores the card name into an  tag onto divs. I have an if sentence where after 12 picks, the card names are appended onto the next div with the same class. It used to work fine, but now I have the divs .display set to none at start and later set it to inline-block manualy, and now it will only append my  onto the first two divs instead of all four the second div just overflows until I run out of cards.

Here's [LOG FILE](http://topdeckandwreck.com/stackOverflow/Susti-2015.2.4-7949902-FRFFRFFRF.txt) that the app opens (you need to download it manualy and then click browse in the fiddle to run it)

Here's a fiddle of the whole thing, hope it's not too confusing

```js
var prelink = "http://mtgimage.com/card/";
var postlink = ".jpg";

var booster = 1;
var pick = 0;
var currentCards = 15;

var sortingCardsInt = 0;

var cards = [];
for(t=0;t<45;t++) {
    cards.push([]);
}
var picks = [];

$("#draftlog").change(function() {
    //hides start message, tip jar
    $('.startMessage').css('display', 'none');
    $('.tipJar').css('display','none');
    //shows picks list
    $('.picks').eq(0).css('display', 'inline-block');
    $('.picks').eq(1).css('display', 'inline-block');
    $('.picks').eq(2).css('display', 'inline-block');
    $('.picks').eq(3).css('display', 'inline-block');
    //removes card container background
    $('.cardcontainer').css('background-image','none');
    //gets first file from draftlog
    var logFile = $('#draftlog').get(0).files[0];     
    //reads first file from draftlog as text
    var reader = new FileReader;
    reader.readAsText(logFile);
    reader.onload = function(e) {
    var rawLog = reader.result;   
    //splits the text into an array of strings for every new line
    var re=/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/g;
    arrayOfLines = rawLog.replace(re,"\n").split("\n");    
    //removes "    "
    for(x=0;x<arrayOfLines.length;x++) {
        arrayOfLines[x] = arrayOfLines[x].replace(/    /g,'');
    }    
    //sorts cards into pick arrays
    sortCards(15);
    sortCards(167);
    sortCards(319);
    //tags picked card
    for(y=0;y<cards.length;y++) {
        for(x=0;x<cards[y].length;x++) {
            var start = cards[y][x].substring(0,4);
            if(start === "--> ") {
                picks.push(x);
                cards[y][x] = cards[y][x].replace(/--> /g,'');
            }
        }
    }    
    //turns picks into links
    for(y=0;y<cards.length;y++) {
    for(x=0;x<cards[y].length;x++) {
        cards[y][x] = prelink.concat(cards[y][x]);
        cards[y][x] = cards[y][x].concat(postlink);
        cards[y][x] = cards[y][x].replace(/ /g,'_');
    }
    }
    loadCards();
};
});

$(".card").hover(
        function() {

        },
        function() {

        });
        
$(".card").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        //formats and appends cardname onto related div
        var cardname = $(this).attr('src');
        cardname = cardname.replace("http://mtgimage.com/card/",'');
        cardname = cardname.replace(".jpg",'');
        cardname = cardname.replace(/_/g,' ');
        if(pick < 12){
        $(".picks").eq(0).append('<a class="picksave">'+cardname+'</a>');
        }
        else if(pick => 12 && pick < 24){
        $(".picks").eq(1).append('<a class="picksave">'+cardname+'</a>');   
        }
        else if(pick => 24 && pick < 36){
        $(".picks").eq(2).append('<a class="picksave">'+cardname+'</a>');
        }
        else if(pick => 36){
        $(".picks").eq(3).append('<a class="picksave">'+cardname+'</a>');
        }
        //counts pick, changes currentCards number
        if (currentCards > 1) {
            pick++;
            currentCards--;
        //opens next booster    
        } else {
            pick++;
            booster++;
            currentCards = 15;
        }
        clearCards();
        loadCards();
    } else {
        //clears all card borders to white
        for(x=0;x<15;x++) {
            $('.card').eq(x).removeClass('selected');
            $('.card').eq(x).css('border','4px solid white');
            $('.historyPick').css('border', '4px solid lime');
        }
        //selects card, makes border gray
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).css('border', '4px solid gray');        
        }
});

function loadCards() {    
    //writes pick onto cards, makes them visible
    for(x=0;x<currentCards;x++) {
        $(".card").eq(x).attr('src', cards[pick][x]);
        $(".card").eq(x).css('display', 'inline');
        $(".card").eq(picks[pick]).addClass('historyPick');
        $('.card').eq(picks[pick]).css('border', '4px solid lime');
    }
};

function clearCards() {
    //hides all cards
    for(x=0;x<15;x++) {
        $('.card').eq(x).css('display', 'none');
        $('.card').eq(x).attr('src', 'http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg');
        $('.card').eq(x).removeClass('historyPick selected');
        $('.card').eq(x).css('border', '4px solid white');
    }
}

function sortCards(num) {
    var currentLine = num;
    var numCards = 15;
    var pickNumber = 0;
    
    for(y=0;pickNumber<15;y++) {
        for(x=0;x<numCards;x++) {
            cards[sortingCardsInt].push(arrayOfLines[currentLine]);
            currentLine++;
        }
        pickNumber++;
        sortingCardsInt++;
        numCards--;
        currentLine +=2;
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color:#0066ff;
}
.cardcontainer {
    margin:auto;
    width:1260px;
    height:650px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:white;
    background-image: url("images/program/cardbox.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
}
.startMessage {
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align: center;
    width: 420px;
    height:325px;
    margin-top:162px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:10%;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:10px;
    opacity:0.8;
}
.cardbox {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width:auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
.card {
    border: 4px solid white;
    width:192px;
    height:272px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display:none;
}
.picksbox {
    width:1260px;
    height:285px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:white;
    background-image:url("images/program/picksbox.jpg");
    border-radius:3px;
}
.tipJar {
    width:146px;
    height:250px;
    background-image:url("images/program/TipJar.jpg");
    background-size:100%;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin:auto;
    opacity:0.7;
    position:relative;
    top:17px;
}
.picks {
    display:none;
    width:315px;
    height:285px;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:auto;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.picksave {
    font-family:verdana;
    margin:5px;
    display:block;
    font-size:14px;
}
.options {
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    width:1260px;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MTGO draft replayer 0.1.3</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cardcontainer">
            <div class ="startMessage">
                <br/>
                Welcome to the TopdeckAndWreck.com MTGO Draft Replayer!<br/>
                <br/>
                In case you're not sure where and how to start check out our tutorial or FAQ pages.<br/>
                <br/>
                Thanks for visiting and have fun!
            </div>
            <div class="cardbox">
                <img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
            </div
            ><div class="cardbox">
                <img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
            </div
            ><div class="cardbox">
                <img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
            </div
            ><div class="cardbox">
                <img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
            </div
            ><div class="cardbox">
                <img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
            </div
            ><div class="cardbox">
                <img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
            </div
            ><div class="cardbox">
                <img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
            </div
            ><div class="cardbox">
                <img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
            </div
            ><div class="cardbox">
                <img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
            </div
            ><div class="cardbox">
                <img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
            </div
            ><div class="cardbox">
                <img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
            </div
            ><div class="cardbox">
                <img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
            </div
            ><div class="cardbox">
                <img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
            </div
            ><div class="cardbox">
                <img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
            </div
            ><div class="cardbox">
                <img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="options">
            <input type="file" name="draftlog" id="draftlog">            
        </div> 
        
        <div class="picksbox">
            <div class='tipJar'></div>
        <div class="picks"></div
        ><div class="picks"></div
        ><div class="picks"></div
        ><div class="picks"></div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="magic.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And you've narrowed down the problem to the *entirety* of that wall of JavaScript? Because it looks like you posted your entire code, rather than the minimal "[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" code required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's really hard to know what I'm talking about without actually seeing how this works and what the actual problem is without seeing the whole thing(can't recreate the problem without reading the log and doing everything else first). I also have no idea why this stopped working, without me changing the if sentence (it's under $('.card').click function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have tested your logical operators, especially the [greater than equal operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Greater_than_or_equal_operator_(%3E.3D)) in the following part of the code:

```
        else if(pick => 12 && pick < 24){
           $(".picks").eq(1).append('<a class="picksave">'+cardname+'</a>');   
        }
        else if(pick => 24 && pick < 36){
           $(".picks").eq(2).append('<a class="picksave">'+cardname+'</a>');
        }
        else if(pick => 36){
           $(".picks").eq(3).append('<a class="picksave">'+cardname+'</a>');
        }
```

When I tested `=>` operator, I got the following error: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>* . Maybe `>=` should be used instead. I hope this helps :-)

```js
console.log( 3 >= 2); //true
console.log( 3 <= 2); //false
//console.log( 3 => 2); //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
```